# Flyway : Oracle db migration not working on flyway 1.6 and 1.7

Tags: java, database, oracle11g, database-migration, flyway

Would appreciate any clues.

I am getting the following exception (for either sql and java migration) when calling the migrate() method, after the table *schema-version* is created on init().

> com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException: Unable to lock
>   metadata table 'schema_version' in schema 'XXX'   at
>   com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTable.lock(MetaDataTable.java:146)

...

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: SQL string is not a DML statement
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1263)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3665)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1352)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:260)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.oracle.OracleDbSupport.lockTable(OracleDbSupport.java:76)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTable.lock(MetaDataTable.java:144)
>     ... 61 more

Thanks.

Comment: what is the name of the schema? (I'm sure XXX is not it :-) ) Does it contain special characters?